# Does Kyle's name on the ServerFault blog about page make sense?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

See below image from the [Server Fault blog about page](http://blog.serverfault.com/about/), but it kind of seems like a mistake that Kyle's name appears here (no offense Kyle, love your work and your blog posts/insight)..

[image: blog about page screenshot]

**Edit**
It is the same as [SO's blog about page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/about/) though...still, I think it needs changing.
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the byline (author of the page) is always stamped under the heading. But yeah, it does look a bit odd.

Comment: @Mark That could make sense...

Comment: It never even occurred to me that Zypher had another name. Then again, I'm just getting used to not seeing Farseeker around here. :)

Comment: It is a wordpress theme thing, don't see an author option for "pages". Will fix it .. eventually :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed see it [here](http://blog.serverfault.com/about/)